# Where does String object get stored in memory when created by StringBuffer?

Tags: java

StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("Java");
Where would String "Java" be created? Normal heap or constant pool?

Next if I modify it as-
str.append(" nine");

Where would the modification happen ? Would it modify the string "Java" in constant pool and convert it to "Java nine"?

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder in 2004.

Comment: Where it is created depends on the version of Java you are using.  The use of StringBuffer dates the question to being before Java 5.0, when it was stored in the perm gen (which no longer exists in the last 3 versions of Java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("Java");` Where would String "Java"
>   be created? Normal heap or constant pool?

That statement doesn't create a String object. It creates a `StringBuffer` object and in the process copies the characters in the string "Java" into the character array maintained internally by `str`. The string "Java" already exists before that statement runs. Roughly speaking, it was created in the constant pool when the class containing this code was initialized.

> Next if I modify it as- `str.append(" nine");`
>
> Where would the modification happen ? Would it modify the string
>   "Java" in constant pool and convert it to "Java nine"?

The modification happens in the internal character array maintained by `str`. The original string "Java" is unaffected. `String` objects in Java are immutable.

Comment: Thanks a ton Mr.Ted ! Your precise explanation has clarified my doubt.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that running the first command will lead to allocation of the StringBuffer's internal array and it will copy the characters "Java" into it, so now the characters will be stored twice - once in the constant pool in the `String` and second time on heap inside `StringBuffer`'s internal character array.